# Sectioned ListView and ExpandableListView

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I need to create a layout with a title bar on the top and a list view with n sections. The
list header of every section has got two distinct Buttons that must be clickable and focusable independently from each other. This is the code of the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/title_bar" />

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dip" 
      android:layout_weight="1.0"   
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried this two solutions but I've found issues that I am not able to solve in both:

1) Using a sectioned adapter (source code can be found [here](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/ListView/Sections/)). It works fine without the title bar but with the title bar the default focus algorithm doesn't work any more.

2) Using an ExpandableListAdapter (in this case obviously the ListView in the layout becomes an ExpandableListView). It works fine but if I press the dpad center button on group layout both buttons are clicked.  I did not find a way to solve this.

Anyone can help?

Thanks very much!

Comment: "The list header of every section has got two distinct Buttons that must be clickable and focusable independently from each other." -- why?

Comment: It's a feature required by the application I am working on. By clicking the 1st button you start an Activity, by clicking the 2nd button you start another one. Anyway the most tedious problem using your implementation is the focus when you add another layout besides the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying Merge adapter https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge it allows you to add multiple list and buttons !!